# DynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation is not a function error in Angular2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use **DynamicComponentLoader** and the sample code is below:

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap,  OnInit, DynamicComponentLoader} from 'angular2';

...

DynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation(PersonsComponent, itemElement);
```

When I run the app, I get the error:

> DynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation is not a function

How can I use DynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation in ES6 JavaScript using class?

Comment: Did you inject it as it's shown in [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DynamicComponentLoader` is **class**. It doesn't have any static method `loadIntoLocation`. But instances of this class have it. You must instantiate `DynamicComponentLoader` using dependency injection:

```
import { Component, View, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef } from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
  selector: 'dc'
})
@View({
  template: '<b>Some template</b>'
})
class DynamicComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
  template: '<div #container></div>'
})
export class App {

  constructor(
    dynamicComponentLoader: DynamicComponentLoader, 
    elementRef: ElementRef
  ) {
    dynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation(DynamicComponent, elementRef, 'container');
  }
}
```

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OEYeJv7UEQMrfTQibpGB?p=preview)

**UPD**

What about ES6, I've answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034930/how-to-use-angular2-dynamiccomponentloader-in-es6/33036634#33036634)

Comment: Thank you. I don't use typescript but ES6 and Babel for transpiling. When I tried the code, I get the error 'NoAnnotationError {message: "Cannot resolve all parameters for ProductsComponen…ake sure they all have valid type or annotations.", stack: "Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for ProductsC…_view_factory.'

Comment: Do you have a sample for ES6? I don't know how to inject to ES6 classes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`DynamicComponentLoader` is long gone.

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader explains how it's done in newer Angular version.

> ```
>   loadComponent() {
>     this.currentAddIndex = (this.currentAddIndex + 1) % this.ads.length;
>     let adItem = this.ads[this.currentAddIndex];
>
>     let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(adItem.component);
>
>     let viewContainerRef = this.adHost.viewContainerRef;
>     viewContainerRef.clear();
>
>     let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
>     (<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).data = adItem.data;
>   }
> ```