# How to use angular2 DynamicComponentLoader in ES6?

Tags: dependency-injection, angular

I'm **not** using typescript but **ES6** and angular2 **alpha39** to load a component dynamically. The following code is similar to what I have in my app. What I have noticed is *angular2* does not create an instance of *DynamicComponentLoader* nor *ElementRef* and inject into the constructor. They are undefined.

How can I do the injection of DynamicComponentLoader using **ES6 and angular2 alpha39**?

```
import {Component, View, Inject, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef } from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
  selector: 'dc',
  bindings: [ DynamicComponentLoader ]
})
@View({
  template: '<b>Some template</b>'
})

class DynamicComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
  template: '<div #container></div>'
})
@Inject(DynamicComponentLoader)
@Inject(ElementRef)
export class App {
  constructor(
    dynamicComponentLoader, 
    elementRef
  ) {
    dynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation(DynamicComponent, elementRef, 'container');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to write code in ES7, I think the most concise approach to specify injections at this time is to use static getter for `parameters`:

```js
import {Component, View, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef } from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
  template: '<div #container></b>'
})
export class App {

  static get parameters() {
    return [[DynamicComponentLoader], [ElementRef]];  
  }

  constructor(dynamicComponentLoader, elementRef) {
    dynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation(DynamicComponent, elementRef, 'container');
  }
}
```

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eZhcTPFUGnATnr3e3lQU?p=preview)

If you want to write code in ES6, which doesn't support decorators, you must also use static getter for `annotations` property. In this case you must import `ComponentMetadata` and `ViewMetadata` instead of `Component` and `View` For example:

```js
import {ComponentMetadata, ViewMetadata, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef } from 'angular2/angular2';

export class App {

  static get annotations() {
    return [
      new ComponentMetadata({
        selector: 'app'
      }),
      new ViewMetadata({
        template: '<div #container></b>'
      })
    ];
  }

  static get parameters() {
    return [[DynamicComponentLoader],[ElementRef]];  
  }

  constructor(dynamicComponentLoader, elementRef) {
    dynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation(DynamicComponent, elementRef, 'container');
  }
}
```

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RrrdCArGWcu5m1NSHCdk?p=preview)

Comment: lifesaver, but now decorators are working for @Component