# Am I able to change templateUrl in angular 2 dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to change my templateUrl dynamically, I've read [Dynamic template URLs in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692416/dynamic-template-urls-in-angular-2). Yes, I can change my template before the component initialize. But what I want is when I hit a button and the url change, then my html is update, like two way data binding.

I try make to my component like this:

```
templateUrl: (function() {
    return dynamicURl;
}())
```

But when change the "dynamicUrl", not thing happened. I also use dynamicComponentLoader load my component again and component is not changed.

Comment: This is a out of date question. Angular only have rc version when I asked this question. Now, you have other ways to update the component template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way you can do it in angular 2 (alpha 48 version) as of now. 
You can refer to : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/ROkKDHboWoA ,

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2753

There is a similar question : [Dynamic template in templatURL in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749994/dynamic-template-in-templaturl-in-angular2)

As it seems that they are not planning to include this, you would like to write your own function to populate the div with dynamic content. Or a similar attribute directive.

Comment: The similar question actually has answers. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42414325/1291428