# How to make nativescript orientation qualifiers work with Angular2?

Tags: angular, telerik, nativescript

NativeScript supports very convenient [orientation qualifiers](http://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#orientation-qualifiers).

Unfortunately, I'm unable to get this work in NativeScript with Angular.

My layout.land.html or layout.land.css is not loaded. 
Even if I will create both layout.port.html and layout.land.html and delete land.html -> app complains that layout.html can not be found.

I suppose it is not supported for Angular apps. If this is the case, are there any workoarounds to load different layout based on orientation or other qualifiers?

I'm aware about [this plugin](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-orientation) but I would preffer above solution bevause it is built in and allows for complete different layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen qualifiers are not currently supported for Angular-2 application.
Also, you can't change templateUrls in Angular-2 at this very moment as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822830/am-i-able-to-dynamic-change-templateurl-in-angular-2).

You can track [this issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/404) where the screen qualifiers usage for NativeScript + Angular-2 is logged as a desired feature.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that issue on github. Didn't notice it ealier.