# setting @Component template dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angular

My template is dynamically derived from the complex rules driven from the Java layer.

Is there a way to dynamically set or update a component's template on `ngOnInit` for instance or wherever appropriate?

Comment: You can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782409/angular-2-stable-templateurl-variable or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410355/how-to-use-variable-to-define-templateurl-in-angular2

Comment: yurzui - how does the template binding work in the newly created component? both examples are close - except that i needed the newly created component to have input and output ideally from the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 allows the component's template to be pointed to a file.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'mycomponent',
    templateUrl: 'views/mycomponent.html'
})
```

You can make it point to a dynamically generated page instead.