# implement ng-include custom directive in Angular2 giving entrycomponents error?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

Previously I am using ng-include in Angular1 for dynamic template loading.

Now I started  Angular2. Angular2 did n't have ng-include feauture.

By this stackoverflow links I get the solution to that custom directive for this feature

[Dynamic template in templatURL in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749994/dynamic-template-in-templaturl-in-angular2)

From solutions for above link post I am facing several issues

I am using Angular2.4.0 version

In above post plunker link is there. If you observe the plunker post there

```
import {
Component, Input, ViewContainerRef, OnInit, ComponentResolver, ViewChild
  } from "@angular/core";
```

`import {FORM_DIRECTIVES} from "@angular/common";`

Now I am unable to get FROM_DIRECTIVES from @angular/common and ComponentResolver from @angular/core.because ComponentResolver is replaced ComponentFactoryResolver .

even I make changes to above plunker link I am getting error

**caused by: No component factory found for MyNgIncludeContent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents**

Even I add entrycomponents to @NgModule decorator.

Please help me to solve this issue, or suggist any better approach.

You can find my issus on https://plnkr.co/edit/XVLcMl?p=preview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular/38888009#38888009

Comment: It's not match my case.above plunker link is suitable for my case which I mentioned