# Can I change the fill color of an svg path ionic2?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm looking for a way to modify the color "fill" attribute of an SVG image

```
<img src="img/icons/main-icons/accounts-icon.svg">
```

accounts-icon.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="enable-background:new 0 0 300 300;" xml:space="preserve">
    <link xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" rel="stylesheet" href="../../../build/css/app.wp.css" type="text/css"/>
<g>
    <path class="st0" ...>
```

How can I change the colors now? Is it even possible?
webkit mask image not working in windows mobile

Style

```
.st0 {
    fill: $theme2-primaryColor;
}
```

Comment: make a div with the svg code directly inside without using an img tag

Comment: have lot of icons  any other possibility

Comment: In Angular 1 you can use ng-include directive... i really don't know if there is something similar in angular 2. Try take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749994/dynamic-template-in-templaturl-in-angular2)