# Dynamic template "transclusion" in Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, transclusion

I am trying to achieve something like this: 
I have a model class called `ObjectTypeA`, `ObjectTypeB` and `ObjectTypeC`. 
There is also a factory `ComponentFactory`, which based on the type of object passed in will create different components:

**ComponentFactory.ts**

```
export interface ComponentFactoryInterface {

    static CreateComponent(obj: CommonSuperObject)

}

@Injectable()
export class ComponentFactory {

    public static CreateComponent(obj: CommonSuperObject){

        if (obj instanceof ObjectTypeA){
            return ObjectComponentA()
        }else if (obj instanceof ObjectTypeB){
            return ObjectComponentB()
        }

    }
}
```

In the template I would like to do something like this:

**main_template.html**

```
<components>
  <component *ngFor="#obj in objects">
     <!-- insert custom component template here -->
  </component>
</components>
```

How do I insert the associated components dynamically ?

I could do something like this (not my preferred way of doing it):

```
<components>
  <!-- loop over component models -->
  <custom-component-a *ngIf="models[i] instanceof ObjectTypeA">
  </custom-component-a>
  <custom-component-b *ngIf="models[i] instanceof ObjectTypeB">
  </custom-component-b>
</components>
```

But this is seems really wrong to me on many levels (I would have to modify this code and the factory code if I add another component type).

## Edit - Working Example

```
constructor(private _contentService: ContentService, private _dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, componentFactory: ComponentFactory, elementRef: ElementRef){

    this.someArray = _contentService.someArrayData;
    this.someArray.forEach(compData => {
    let component = componentFactory.createComponent(compData);
        _dcl.loadIntoLocation(component, elementRef, 'componentContainer').then(function(el){
            el.instance.compData = compData;
        });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**

DCL is deprecated since a while. Use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` instead. For an example (with Plunker) see [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

**original**

You can use `ngSwitch` (similar to your own workaround but more concise)  or `DynamicComponentLoader`

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html
- [How to use angular2 DynamicComponentLoader in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034930/how-to-use-angular2-dynamiccomponentloader-in-es6)

Comment: `ngSwitch` is not an option, `DynamicComponentLoader` sounds more like what I am looking for. I'll take a look at that and get back to you.

Comment: Phew! Almost there, I only need to set a property on the newly created component. I get the promise with the `ComponentRef` back but I'm not really sure how to access properties of the newly loaded component... Any idea ? (Updated my question for you to see what I am working with)

Comment: Okay, I think the component instance would be `el.instance`. Trying that out and getting back to you shortly.

Comment: Okay got it! Your tip was immensely helpful! Vielen Dank und frohe Weihnachten!

Comment: Since rc1 DynamicComponentLoader has become deprecated.

Comment: @AlexandreJunges thanks for the hint :) I updated my answer.